# Forge Model Properties Excel

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

Currently I was following these steps to get the Forge Viewer into PowerBi. I was able to successfully get that to work but now I am attempting to get the properties out of the revit models.

I am following these steps found [here](https://github.com/xiaodongliang/forgeviewer_embed_in_powerbi_report)

by editing this package [forge-model-properties-excel](https://github.com/xiaodongliang/forgeviewer_embed_in_powerbi_report/tree/master/forge-model-properties-excel)

I am putting in a revit model that shows up as a 3D model in Forge viewer, and I know it has the material properties that I need. But when i run it i get the error that reads

> this model has no {3D} view

I'm not sure why I am receiving this error if the model does have a 3D view.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The sample application is looking for a 3D view that is actually called "{3D}": https://github.com/xiaodongliang/forgeviewer_embed_in_powerbi_report/blob/70c58ab3217cdf4b10c475abf2721871984ed4e0/forge-model-properties-excel/index.js#L27.

Is it possible that the 3D views in your Revit model are named differently? If they are, make sure to update that line of code with the expected name.